# CUDA error: an illegal memory access while training a deep learning model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train a deep learning model on a custom dataset for semantic segmentation. The link to the github repo of the model is mentioned below.

https://github.com/XuJiacong/PIDNet

When I am trying to train on my PC, I am getting the following error.

```
 File "tools/train.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "tools/train.py", line 185, in main
    train(config, epoch, config.TRAIN.END_EPOCH, 
  File "/home/deshpand/thesis_rr/semantic_segmentation_network/PIDNet/tools/../utils/function.py", line 43, in train
    losses, _, acc, loss_list = model(images, labels, bd_gts)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 169, in forward
    return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/thesis_rr/semantic_segmentation_network/PIDNet/tools/../utils/utils.py", line 48, in forward
    loss_s = self.sem_loss(outputs[:-1], labels)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/thesis_rr/semantic_segmentation_network/PIDNet/tools/../utils/criterion.py", line 90, in forward
    return sum([
  File "/home/deshpand/thesis_rr/semantic_segmentation_network/PIDNet/tools/../utils/criterion.py", line 91, in <listcomp>
    w * func(x, target)
  File "/home/deshpand/thesis_rr/semantic_segmentation_network/PIDNet/tools/../utils/criterion.py", line 72, in _ohem_forward
    pred, ind = pred.contiguous().view(-1,)[mask].contiguous().sort()
RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

This is the first time I have seen error like this. Can someone please explain what is going on here?

The specifications for my GPU are as follows.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.86.01    Driver Version: 515.86.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 25%   36C    P0    29W / 120W |    648MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       902      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                245MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1234      G   /usr/bin/kwin_x11                 123MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1289      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell               48MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1481      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          173MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5801      G   ...RendererForSitePerProcess       49MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I will really appreciate the help here. Also, I am using PyTorch version 1.13.1

```
>>> print(torch.__version__)
1.13.1
>>>
```

Comment: @Akshay Hiramath do you know any solution to this?

Comment: I would recommend to run it on cpu, verify the code is working. Most of times, when I got this error, I had bugs in my code, and switching to cpu helps in detecting it.